# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Position' and 'Position'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have the class

```
class Position():
    def __init__(self, line, column):
        self.line = line
        self.column = column
```

I have created `delta`, but an object of type `Position` can't be used as an argument.

```
delta = lambda position1, position2 : tuple(np.abs(np.subtract(position1, position2)))
```

Suppose `position1 = Position(1,2)` and `position2 = Position(5,6)`. Is there a way to run `delta(position1, position2)` without created an error?

Comment: can you explain what you want to do because there is 2 numbers in each object (line and column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a `__sub__` and `__abs__` magic methods in your class. Also, if you want to use arrays of `position1` and `position2`, you will also have to implement a `__array_wrap__` magic method.

Also, I don't find the use of `tuple` very appropriate here. If you want to use that too, you will have to change the implementation of class `Position` and return a `Sequence` object instead.

```py
class Position:
    def __init__(self, a, b): 
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Position(self.a - other.a, self.b - other.b)

    def __abs__(self):
        return Position(abs(self.a), abs(self.b))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you return for instance of class is a instance of a class not sequence, like list, tuple, integer, float, ..., not working in np operations.

Should use def __new__, not __init__

```py
import numpy as np

class Position(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, column, row):
        return super().__new__(cls, (column, row))

delta = lambda position1, position2 : tuple(np.abs(np.subtract(position1, position2)))

position1 = Position(1,2)
position2 = Position(5,6)

print(delta(position1, position2))
```